# Calling methods in third-party DLLs

Tags: c#, qt, pinvoke, marshalling, intptr

I'm using C# and P-Invoke to get access to objects in the Qt framework (http://qt.digia.com/). I don't seem to be having trouble using functions that return simple types (or void), but whenever I try to use a function that returns an object, the application crashes.

For example, in QtXml4.dll, there is a method QXmlInputSource::data(void) that returns an object of type QString. Here is my wrapper class:

```
public class QXmlInputSource
{
    // PInvoke - class QString QXmlInputSource::data(void)
    [DllImport("QtXml4.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Unicode, EntryPoint = "?data@QXmlInputSource@@UBE?AVQString@@XZ",
        SetLastError = true, CallingConvention = CallingConvention.ThisCall)]
    static extern IntPtr data(ref IntPtr Ptr);

    private IntPtr mPtr;

    public QXmlInputSource(IntPtr Ptr)
    {
        mPtr = Ptr;
    }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        IntPtr mData = data(ref mPtr);
        return "Epic Fail";
    }

}
```

And here is some code that hooks (using EasyHook) into a function call that provides a valid QXmlInputSource object:

```
    // just use a P-Invoke implementation to get native API access from C# (this step is not necessary for C++.NET)
    [DllImport("QtXml4.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Unicode, EntryPoint = "?parse@QXmlSimpleReader@@UAE_NPBVQXmlInputSource@@@Z",
        SetLastError = true, CallingConvention = CallingConvention.ThisCall)]
    [return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)]
    static extern bool XmlParse(IntPtr Reader, IntPtr Source);

    // Intercept all calls to parse XML
    public bool XmlParse_Intercepted(IntPtr Reader, IntPtr Source)
    {
        QXmlInputSource XmlSource = new QXmlInputSource(Source);
        String s = XmlSource.ToString();

        // call original API...
        return XmlParse(Reader, Source);
    }
```

The hooking code seems to work fine. The Qt application crashes when I make the call to the data() function in my wrapper class. As I said above, the Qt-based application seems to crash whenever the function call returns an object rather than a simple type.

I've tried various combinations of CallingConventions, return types, Marshaling, etc. but haven't stumbled on anything that actually works.

Any help much appreciated.

Also a general thank you to all the contributors on the site - it's an invaluable resource!

Comment: Have you tried to ommit the entry points and just tried to access the library directly?

Comment: No, because without the EntryPoint attribute, I don't know what function name to use for the static extern declaration. Remember these are member functions of objects, not static functions. The decorated name (e.g. "?parse@QXml...") is necessary to identify the right method.

Comment: So, have you considered, that if you don't have an object (an instance), you can't call methods?

Comment: I have.I'm using an instance from within the Qt application - I get an IntPtr reference to it by hooking a specific call. "IntPtr Source" is the reference to the instance of QXmlInputSource, and I am trying to inspect the XML data inside it by calling the data() method on it.

Comment: Are you trying to return data before reading?? You are calling `.ToString()` before calling XmlParse, is that intended?

Comment: I think so, yes. In the hooking code, the XmlReader parses the XmlSource, so I'm assuming that there is data in it. It's _possible_ that there will be no data in it after I make the call to XmlParse, which is why I try to inspect the data() before I call XmlParse.

Comment: Try the other way 'round... Worst could be, that nothing changes!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot possibly hope to call a C++ library like this using P/invoke. You've simply got the wrong tool for the job.

What you need to do is use a C++/CLI mixed mode layer to do the work. Not only will this have the obvious benefit of actually working, it will be far easier too. Write C++ code that calls the native Qt DLLs. Then expose that code to your C# using managed classes. Finally you can simply add a reference to the C++/CLI library from your C# code and it's all good.

Comment: There is always hope!! :P I'll take your word for it though. I'm sure I'l be back in a day or two with another question ...

Comment: Until you have some more rep, all you can do is accept answers. Anyway, I'll give you some rep by upvoting your question which is a good question. I often forget to upvote questions.